# Time profiler in Instruments

Tags: iphone, xcode, profiling, instruments

I am having trouble launching Time Profiler in Xcode, both for Mac Applications and iPhone apps.

The steps I have tried are opening Time Profiler, Clicking the choose target drop down box, selecting my iPhone or Mac book. Choose target -> myApp. If I choose a Mac app then I hit the record button a big yellow warning pops up accross the window saying unable to configure sampling trigger for x. If I choose an iPod app then the record button stays greyed out and cannot be clicked.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried starting Instruments via (in Xcode) `Run -> Run with Performance Tool -> Time Profiler`? That may help set up Instruments and get you running v. launching Instruments manually.

Also, I have had trouble in the past where the SDK used to build the iPhone app differed from that which Instruments was expecting. Check out the Instruments documentation on how to explicitly tell it which version of the iOS you are running to perform the benchmarking.

Comment: For some reason the Time Profiler is greyed out in the list that pops up in Run -> Run with Performance Tool.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Time profiler is greyed out because you dont have application install on simulator...if you have application installed on simulator and then you try Run with Performance Tool it shows Time profiler enabled.